# Pixi.jsのインポート

Tags: pixi.js

npm install pixi.js
でPixiをとってきたのですが、
どこからなにをimport Script src = すればよいのかわかりません。
インポート方法からじっくり書かれているHello Worldをつくる手順サイトがあったら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

バージョン5でimport周りが少し変わったので、Web上には紛らわしい情報もあるかもしれません。

GitHubでPixiJS用のテンプレートプロジェクトを公開しているので、よかったら見てみてください。
https://github.com/zprodev/pixi-dev-template

Answer (score 0):

[PixiJS のドキュメント](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/index.html)にはこう書かれています。

> **Learn**
>
> - Website: Find out more about PixiJS on the [official website](https://www.pixijs.com/).
> - Getting started: Check out @kittykatattack's comprehensive [tutorial](https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi).
> - Examples: Get stuck right in and play around with PixiJS code and features right [here](http://pixijs.github.io/examples/)!
> - Docs: Get to know the PixiJS API by checking out the [docs](https://pixijs.github.io/docs/).
> - Wiki: Other misc tutorials and resources are [on the Wiki](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/wiki).

書かれている通り、英語ではありますがとりあえずこのチュートリアルが参考になります。

https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi